# I would like to look into an object to see if element ErrorCode has zero

Tags: xml, vb.net

I would like to check inside my Object named **objXmlCaseListResponseElement** to see if the child element known as **ErrorCode** has a zero in it. If it does not have a zero, I want show an error message and then exit sub

I am not sure how to make my if statement work. So that I am able to read the value inside ErrorCode to see if is not zero and then display the error message.

Here is the vb.net object name **objXmlCaseListResponseElement**

```
objXmlCaseListResponseElement = objCourtRecordService.GetCaseList(objXmlEfsCaseListRequestDoc.DocumentElement)
```

This object **objXmlCaseListResponseElement** contains the following xml document

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CaseListResponseMessage xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CaseListResponseMessage-4.0" xmlns:ecf="urn:oasis:names:tc:legalxml-courtfiling:schema:xsd:CommonTypes-4.0">
    <ecf:Error>
        <ecf:ErrorCode>0</ecf:ErrorCode>

    </ecf:Error>
</CaseListResponseMessage>
```

Here is what I am trying but it wont work. I am getting an error Option Strict On disallows implicit conversions from 'String' to 'Double.'

```
objXmlCaseListResponseElement = objCourtRecordService.GetCaseList(objXmlEfsCaseListRequestDoc.DocumentElement)

  If objXmlCaseListResponseElement.SelectSingleNode("ecf:Error/ecf:ErrorCode", aobjXmlNamespaceManager).InnerText <> 0 Then
        aobjBroker.Reply(ProduceServiceInformationResponseMessage(aobjXmlInputSoapEnvelopeDoc, aobjXmlRequestMessageNode, aobjConsumer, strCaseTrackingID, intNodeID, strCourtORI, strCourtName, aobjXmlNamespaceManager, astrVersionLevel, aobjBroker, 1, "Invalid ErrorCode"))
       Exit Sub
End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [XMLNode's InnerText Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnode.innertext(v=vs.110).aspx) is a string.  When you do boolean evaluations with Option Strict on, you must ensure the types on both sides of the equation are the same.  The simple solution to your problem is to wrap 0 in quotes to make it a string:

```
If objXmlCaseListResponseElement.SelectSingleNode("ecf:Error/ecf:ErrorCode", aobjXmlNamespaceManager).InnerText <> "0" Then
    aobjBroker.Reply(ProduceServiceInformationResponseMessage(aobjXmlInputSoapEnvelopeDoc, aobjXmlRequestMessageNode, aobjConsumer, strCaseTrackingID, intNodeID, strCourtORI, strCourtName, aobjXmlNamespaceManager, astrVersionLevel, aobjBroker, 1, "Invalid ErrorCode"))
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: If I want to count an element to see if it exists more than once how do I do that? I do not want to submit another question because I will lose points. Please help. Thanks so much for your help. That means simple enough to solve my problem! Quick question.

Comment: Check SelectNodes out (instead of SelectSingleNode): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4bektfx9(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks again for your response and help.